# refrshing table after every insert

Tags: python, sqlite, treeview

Hello i am facing an issue trying to refresh the table values after inserting a value i did find a way to insert value to table but i am facing an issue after add one more row to the table i have to close the software and start it again

```
class mainGui(ttk.Frame):
def __init__(self):
    Frame.__init__(self,background="lightblue")
    self.master.title("Family book library")
    self.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
    toolBar = Frame(self)


    self.buttonPicRef = PhotoImage(file="Refresh.png")
    ref = ttk.Button(toolBar, image= self.buttonPicRef)
    ref.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.buttonPicInsert = PhotoImage(file="insert.png")
    addbook = ttk.Button(toolBar,image = self.buttonPicInsert,command = self.fitcher)
    addbook.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.buttonPicAnalyse = PhotoImage(file="analys.png")
    analysis = ttk.Button(toolBar, image = self.buttonPicAnalyse,command = analysFun)
    analysis.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.buttonPicSearch = PhotoImage(file="search.png")
    search = ttk.Button(toolBar, image = self.buttonPicSearch)
    search.pack(side=LEFT)
    toolBar.pack(side=LEFT)

    menu = Menu(self.master)
    self.master.config(menu=menu)
    file = Menu(menu)
    file.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)


    tree = ttk.Treeview(show="headings", height=32)
    tree["columns"] = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" ,"8")

    tree.column("1", width=132)
    tree.column("2", width=302)
    tree.column("3", width=302)
    tree.column("4", width=142)
    tree.column("5", width=123)
    tree.column("6", width=120)
    tree.column("7", width=120)
    tree.column("8", width=120)

    tree.heading("1", text="BookID")
    tree.heading("2", text="BookTitle")
    tree.heading("3", text="BookAuthor")
    tree.heading("4", text="BookPublisher")
    tree.heading("5", text="edition")
    tree.heading("6", text="PublisherDate")
    tree.heading("7", text="familyOwner")
    tree.heading("8", text="Location")




    conn = sqlite3.connect('books.sqlite')
    c = conn.cursor()

    count = c.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM library')
    countf = c.fetchall()
    num = countf[0][0]

    totle = c.execute('SELECT * FROM library')
    totlef = c.fetchall()

    rows = None
    for rows in range(0, num):
         rows

    for values in totlef:
         values[0]
         values[1]
         values[2]
         values[3]
         values[4]
         values[5]
         values[6]
         values[7]
         tree.insert('', rows,values=(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5], values[6], values[7]))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


    tree.pack(side=TOP)
```

the software start normally but the update from the top level windows dose not show tell the user close and open i thought of starting a new Button called 
*buttonPicRef*

Comment: 'return' leaves the current function call.

Comment: @Wolfgang sorry i don't get what u are saying

Comment: You can use the generator. 'return [x for list in rows for x in list]'

Comment: @isslam_akkilah can answer this please when you come

Comment: @isslam_akkilah just write a hint